# Some Styles of Installed Fonts Are Missing or "Overlap"

Tags: windows-7, fonts

I recently purchased a full set of Futura for a class design project, largely to get a variety of different weights and styles (the project is typography based). I took delivery of the fonts as a set of 21 TTF files, but when I try to install them on Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit, only 6 or 7 styles appear in Illustrator or Word when I try to use the font.

I found this (below) which appears to be the same problem, but there's no evidence of a fix here and I really don't have the option of giving up on the font - the assignment gave us a small number of fonts to choose from, and Futura is far and away the most interesting option.

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/some-styles-of-installed-fonts-are-missing-or/f9ae2de9-5f84-4ed7-8198-c9282ea68aea?tm=1315399626275

Has anyone else encountered this issue and found a workaround? (Or failing that, does anyone know where I can get a piece of software that will let me edit the typeface name so that the different styles don't group?)

Comment: I'm having a problem that may or may not be related. I'm trying to copy the Futura font pack from my Mac to my Windows machine. After converting the TTC to Windows-compatible TTFs via an online font converter, the fonts show up just fine when previewed individually in Windows. However, when I try to install them, Futura Condensed Medium and Futura Medium "shadow" each other. Whichever one is installed first is the only one that shows up, and if I then delete the font from my Fonts directory, the shadowed one pops up in its place. Futura Condensed Extra Bold and Futura Medium Italic work fine.

Comment: My guess is some sort of metadata conflict or error, but I used all the tools I could find to figure out the problem (including the incredibly powerful FontForge) and so far haven't found anything. I'll update the thread if I find a solution.

One hacky fix, by the way, is to use a tool (FontForge or Typograf, for instance) to change the family name from Futura to something else for the missing fonts (eg. "Futura Fix 1", "Futura Fix 2", etc.). That way, Windows doesn't try to combine them, preventing the shadowing from occurring. But again, perhaps this is a different problem.

Comment: After some more research, it appears that the fonts that get shadowed are condensed/regular. I guess Windows is confused about that distinction.

Answer (score 0):

[FontForge](http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/) may be of some help in renaming the font families.

Answer (score 0):

FontForge does indeed solve this issue.  I will be kinder, however, and actually tell you HOW to solve the issue using FontForge.

#### Relevant Links:

[FontForge download Page](https://fontforge.org/en-US/)

[Hickory Jack font](https://www.dafont.com/hickory-jack.font) (with a Regular and Light version)

Download and install FontForge (free).  Create a folder for the Hickory Jack font.  Download the Hickory Jack font (comes in a ZIP).  Extract the two files to the folder you created.

Hickory Jack is a free font that exhibits the listed behavior - namely, that installing the two font files results in one font listed in Windows.  Deleting the one font listed (which is always the font file installed last) reveals the other remaining font.

### Open the Fonts

Start FontForge.  Navigate to your folder with the fonts, then choose the font file named "Hickory Jack.ttf".

Now repeat these instructions to open the file named "Hickory Jack Light.ttf".  You now have two copies of FontForge running.

To make it easy on yourself, move and size the windows so that the "Hickory Jack" window is to the left side of your screen, and the "Hickory Jack Light" window is to the right side.

### Edit Bad/Missing Font Metadata

For each instance, choose ELEMENT * FONT INFO (or CTRL-SHIFT-F).  This opens the **Font Information** window.  These windows appear in the center of the screen, so you should move them to the left or right.

Choose **PS Names** option on the left edge.
Change the **Weight** values for each font (initially they are identical):

- Hickory Jack:  Change "Book" to "Regular"
- Hickory Jack Light:  Change "Book" to "Light"

Choose **OS/2** option on the left edge.
Change the **Weight Class** values for Hickory Jack Light:

- Hickory Jack:  Should be "400 Regular"
- Hickory Jack Light:  Change from "400 Regular" to "300 Light"

Choose **TTF Names** option on the left edge.
Compare the two fonts.  This information is correct.  You can see that you are able to change text info here as well.  The most important thing:  no two fonts should have the same **UniqueID** value.

Click OK on both the Font Information windows.  You have successfully corrected the metadata.

### Regenerate The Font Files

The original fonts are True Type fonts (TTF).  We will be saving these as Open Type fonts (OTF).

For the Hickory Jack font, choose FILE * GENERATE FONTS (or type CTRL-SHIFT-G).  This shows the **Generate Fonts** window.

Choose OpenType (CFF) from the drop list so the font changes are saved as OTF files.  It suggests a filename (HickoryJack.otf), but you should change it to **HickoryJack-Regular.otf**.  Click **Generate**.  A window appears titled "Errors Detected".  These are not really errors, so ignore them and click the **Generate** button.

For the Hickory Jack Light font, choose FILE * GENERATE FONTS (or type CTRL-SHIFT-G).

It suggests a filename (HickoryJack-Light.otf) which is perfect.  Click **Generate**.  A window appears titled "Errors Detected".  Again, ignore this message and click the **Generate** button.

### Move or Delete the Old, Bad Font Files

You should now have four files in the font folder you made:

- Hickory Jack Light.ttf
- Hickory Jack.ttf
- HickoryJack-Regular.otf
- HickoryJack-Light.otf

You can delete the TTF files.  You can also install the OTF font files, and you'll notice immediately that Windows now properly groups them together (called Family Grouping).

### Why Did This Work?

Sometimes fonts have incorrect metadata.  You saw how many options there are, so it's not exactly difficult to see how mistakes could be made.

In this case, Windows seemed to see the two fonts as identical since the **OS/2 Weight Class** values were the same.  To Windows, both fonts were in the same **family** (Hickory Jack) and had the same **weight** (Regular), making them essentially the same font.  Therefore it was not necessary to load or expose the second font to applications.

In Windows, fonts with the same Family Name are grouped together.  Fonts that are grouped together can interfere with each other if they have the same weight.

So now you know how to solve TWO problems:

- If you install several fonts that should be grouped together as a Family, but they show up as individual fonts with similar names, you can force them to group together by setting their **PS Names:Family Name** values to be the same.
- If several fonts in the same family are installed, but don't all show up in Windows Fonts, you may need to change the **OS/2:Weight Class** values for the fonts so that Windows sees them as different fonts.